# Menu Customization

Tags: wpf, customization

I would like to repeat the design of JetBrains dotPeek in my program. I would like to know which properties of `Menu` are responsible for these colors:

[image]

Comment: I would suggest getting a copy of the Menu Template through something like Expression Blend, and playing with the colors there to see what area that is. You can also find an example Menu Template [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752296) if you don't have Expression Blend

Comment: Everything in the screen shot look like default Win7 aero colors. In other words, I don't think dotPeek has any special color combination in their menu.